# A congruence involving roots of unity

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, number-fields

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and suppose $f(\omega^j) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $j= 1, \dots, n$ where $\omega = e^{2 \pi i/n}$ is a primitive $n^{\text{th}}$ root of unity.

Computational evidence suggests

$$
f(\omega^{p^e}) \equiv f(\omega^{p^{e-1}}) (\text{mod } p^e),
$$ 
for all primes $p$ and positive integers $e \geq 1$.

**Is there a proof, or a counterexample?**

Note that by Euler's theorem, for every $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\text{gcd}(a,n) = 1$ we have
$$
a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 (\text{mod }n),
$$
where $\phi(n) = |\{ k \in [n] : \text{gcd}(n,j) = 1 \}|$ denotes Euler's totient function.

In particular if $n = p^e$, then $\phi(p^e) = p^e-p^{e-1}$ so

$$
a^{p^e-p^{e-1}} \equiv 1 (\text{mod }p^e),
$$
whenever $\text{gcd}(a,p) = 1$.

Thus by modular arithmetic we can move the modulo inside the argument and get

$$
f(x^{p^e}) = f(x^{p^e-p^{e-1}} x^{p^{e-1}}) \equiv f(x^{p^{e-1}}) (\text{mod } p^e).
$$

Therefore the congruence holds for all integer polynomials at all integer points relatively prime to $p$. My question is if this congruence can be lifted to $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity if $f(x)$ takes integer values at all $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity?

By the way, if $f(\omega^j) \in \mathbb{Z}$, then it is well-known that $f(\omega^j) \in \mathbb{Z}[\omega + \omega^{-1}]$, so (ignoring the constant term) $f(x)$ has palindromic coefficients.

Comment: It is just that for $m | n$ and $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q})$ then $f(\sigma(\zeta_m))=\sigma(f(\zeta_m)) = f(\zeta_m)$.

Comment: If $f(\omega^j)=a_j$, then $\prod_j(f(x)-a_j)$ vanishes at $\omega^j$ for all $j$, so it's a multiple of the minimal polynomial for $\omega$, so for some $j$, $f(x)-a_j$ is a multiple of the minimal polynomial for $\omega$. I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Wild guess, but could we find an integer square matrix $A$ such that $f\left(\omega^k\right) = \operatorname{Tr}\left(A^k\right)$ for all $k\geq 0$ ? Because then, Gert Almkvist's "Integrity of ghosts" would do the rest for us.

Comment: @reuns Yes, in fact I think $f(\omega^k) = f(\omega^{\text{gcd}(n,k)})$.

Comment: See also [Jacques Desarmenien, *Etude modulo n des statistiques mahoniennes*](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~slc/opapers/s22desar.pdf) (unofficial translation, perhaps soon to go onto the arXiv: https://www.dropbox.com/s/miovfhi87ftv0iy/desarmenien%20-%20mahonian%20statistics%20mod%20n%20-%20translation%20-%20version%202017.pdf?dl=0 ) . The concept of polynomials that are "even modulo $n$" is equivalent to your $f\left(\omega^j\right) \in \mathbb{Z}$ condition in the case of polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ of degree $< n$. (And you can WLOG assume that your polynomial has degree $< n$.)

Comment: @user94267 You didn't get my point ? $\sigma(\omega^{kl})  = \omega^{klp}$ comes from a field automorphism $\in Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\omega^k)/\mathbb{Q})$ iff $p \nmid \frac{n}{(n,k)}$. In that case since $f(\omega^k) \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $$f(\omega^k)= \sigma(f(\omega^k)) = f(\sigma(\omega^k)) = f(\omega^{kp})$$ Otherwise if $p \mid \frac{n}{(n,k)}$ you can easily construct some $f$ such that $f(\omega^k)\ne f(\omega^{kp})$. With $k = p^{e-1}$ it means it will fail when $ p^e | n$.

Comment: Ah! WLOG assume that the polynomial $f$ has degree $< n$ (otherwise, we can simply reduce it modulo $x^n-1$). Then, this polynomial is "even modulo $n$" in the sense of Desarmenien's above paper. This means that if we write $f$ as $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i x^i$, then $a_i = a_{\gcd\left(i, n\right)}$ for each $i$. Thus, $f$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of polynomials of the form $\sum_{0\leq i<n;\  \gcd\left(i,n\right) = d} x^i$ for $d \mid n$. By an inclusion-exclusion-style argument, we thus conclude that $f$ is also ...

Comment: ... a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of polynomials of the form $x^{0d} + x^{1d} + x^{2d} + \cdots + x^{n-d}$ for $d \mid n$. So we can WLOG assume that $f$ is one such polynomial; i.e., that we have $f = x^{0d} + x^{1d} + x^{2d} + \cdots + x^{n-d}$ for some $d \mid n$. Fix this $d$. Then, $f\left(\omega^k\right)$ equals $n/d$ if $n \mid kd$, and equals $0$ otherwise. From here, the claim is straightforward.

Comment: By the way, this proves a stronger statement: namely, $f\left(\omega^k\right) \equiv f\left(\omega^{k/p}\right) \mod p^{v_p\left(k\right)}$ for every positive integer $k$ and every prime divisor $p$ of $k$ (where $v_p$ denotes $p$-adic valuation). In other words, $\left(f\left(\omega^1\right), f\left(\omega^2\right), f\left(\omega^3\right), \ldots\right)$ is a [ghost-Witt vector](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126998/criteria-for-ghost-witt-vectors-looking-for-history-and-references) over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Wow, excellent! I think I now follow you argument, and you even characterize all integer polynomials taking integer values at root of unity via a basis. if you feel like making that an answer I will accept it.